# Moving in UINavigationController to controller without NavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, pushviewcontroller

In my iOS app i got two `UIViewControllers`. I moving from one to another with UINavigationController. But first one with UINavigationBar, when in second i type in viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

Then when i open it - on first controller appears big black line on the top. You can see it on image's top left corner:

[image]

How should i open it without this black line.

Comment: on your first view controllers viewWillAppear method you have to add this line of code

self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

Comment: In every viewcontroller you have to write this code self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES

Answer (score 1):

On your first view controllers viewWillAppear method you have to add this line of code

`self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;`

Put this code where you don't want to show **UINavigationController**.

Answer (score 1):

As variant you could add your view on the top in `viewDidLoad` method of your ViewController:

```
UIView *magicView = ...;

[self.navigationController.topViewController.view addSubview:magicView];
```

So in will be above the top of `self.view`.

But you should change all logic from `self.view` to `magicView` (all subviews, all callbacks, etc.)